# Angular material autocomplete: testing events

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-material2

How do I test events in Angular Material Autocomplete? I'm trying to test this code and would like to know how to pass in the `event` argument to the method:

```
onOptionSelect(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
  this.selectedOption = event.option.value;
}
```

**Edit**: To clarify, I'd like to know how to mock an event of type `MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent` so that I can pass it to my method in test.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of creating a whole Event object, you can create only a plain object with values required only by the test and use the **as** keyword to inform the compiler to treat this object as MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent .

```
// given
const newValue = 'something';
const event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent = {
  option: {
    value: newValue
  }
} as MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent;
// when
component.onSelect(event);
// then
expect(component.selectedOption).toEqual(newValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options. You can either call the method directly from your test, or trigger the method using `DebugElement.triggerEventHandler`. In both cases you need to create the event object yourself or mock it and test for the expected results.

If you want to actually force a manual selection, for example open the list and generate a click event on one of the options, I don't think this is possible (I have tried and searched to no avail - if someone knows how, please post the answer). Arguably, this isn't necessary because it doesn't accomplish anything more than one of the above approaches other than making sure that MatAutocomplete makes selections properly, and you shouldn't have to test that IMO.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear in my question. I'm definitely calling the method directly, since there's no need for me to trigger the event (as you pointed.) I don't know how to mock the event. I tried instantiating a new MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent but don't know how to pass in the constructor arguments.

Comment: Hello @Devin, did you solve the problem ? I have the same one :/

Comment: @Neamesis Sorry, I don't have access to the code base anymore mate. Perhaps you could check the Angular src code to see how they handle tests? It's quite comprehensive.